# delete from three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

**Please Anyone there**
***if any conditions or query***

i need to delete the details are matching accroding to
Table adl_auth_user A

```
id      user_id     type_id     type_value  
66428     1919          1           97
```

table user_details B

```
user_id     first_name      last_nam    
1919        Rins TE       Kola
```

table adl_user C

```
id         email                   password 
1919    email@DOMAIN.COM         SOME PASSWORD
```

> i want delete from these three

```
tables table1. user_id = table2.
> user_id and table1. user_id = table3.id
```

and group by

> table1.type_id,table1.type_value

Comment: So... did you just post your password for your gmail accounts?!?

Comment: Do you want to delete from 'adl_auth_user' Table? or Delete from the three tables?

Comment: nop this is just waste all things are edited format

Comment: i want delete from these three tables table1. user_id = table2. user_id and table1. user_id = table3.id and group by table1.type_id,table1.type_value

Comment: Why do you want to Group?

Comment: there is huge data with data i am passing id =1919

Answer (score 0):

try this . delete the records from table according to the table dependencies.

```
i think grouping is not required as you are trying to delete the records


DELETE FROM adl_auth_user 
from adl_auth_user  A 
INNER JOIN user_details  B ON a.user_id=B.user_id
INNER JOIN adl_user  C ON b.user_id=c.id
WHERE A.user_id =1919 AND A.type_id =1

DELETE FROM user_details  
FROM user_details B 
INNER JOIN adl_user C ON b.user_id=c.id
WHERE B.user_id =1919 

DELETE FROM adl_user  
WHERE adl_user .id =1919
```